# Hide SVG element from C#

Tags: c#, svg, visibility

I have a `svg` which contains two groups.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="gr1" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
  </g>
  <g id="gr2" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="25" />
    <circle cx="96" cy="40" r="25" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way, using C# or javascript (preferably C#), to hide the group gr2 at some event (button click, x value>y value, etc)? I know that `visibility="hidden"` does what I want, but I don't know how to call it for a group of my SVG.

Comment: Did you tried to use `jquery` for this ?

Comment: Salut! N-am incercat. As prefera sa fac acest lucru pe C#. Ce optiuni am in jquery?

Comment: `g.style("display", "none");`

Comment: Is this an MVC project? We need some more code to help you.

Comment: And how could I identify gr2? Could i do something like this: gr2.style("display", "none") ?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras, it's not a MVC project. I'm using WebForms. How I wrote above, I want to hide, for example, the second group when an event occurs.

Comment: Ionut you can talk to any control from the server by adding the runat="server" and giving it a id.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan, yes, but if this svg is called in an asp image, how could I hide the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<svg  viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="gr1" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
  </g>
  <g runat="server"  id="gr2" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="25" />
    <circle cx="96" cy="40" r="25" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

and in c#

```
{
    gr2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the entire SVG, but only gr2.

Comment: OK. It works. Thanks!
Though I have a question: if this SVG is called in an asp image, how could I hide the group?

Comment: You cannot do it this way. The asp image is one and the svg will be loaded as a static resource from your web server. Then, depending on how the browser will render the svg (I haven't checked) you will need som javascript to solve this.

Comment: Do you have, please, an example how could I do this in javascript? I'm asking you this because I have and other complex SVGs which I cannot include in my aspx page and I have to call it through asp image. Many thanks! :)

Comment: There is a basic example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp You can add an id attribute on your svg and hide it with an onClick event from your javascript. I will need to see a more comprehensive example (maybe a new question on this) to help you more.

Comment: I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263345/hide-aspimage-svg-elements
Many thanks!