# Hide asp:Image SVG elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, svg

I have a complex `SVG`, but for demonstration purpose I will use one which contains only two groups.

```
<svg id="sv" viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="gr1" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
  </g>
  <g id="gr2" fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="25" />
    <circle cx="96" cy="40" r="25" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

This SVG is called in an `asp:Image` like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" Visible="true" Style="align-content: center;" ImageUrl="~/Img/circle.svg" />
```

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262595/hide-svg-element-from-c-sharp#59262788) how could I hide an element from my SVG.

My question is how could I hide, for example, gr2  from the svg which is called in the `asp:Image`?

Comment: Is that not possible to hide by ('#gr2').css('visibility','hidden')?

Comment: And how could specify from which image "gr2"is form?

Comment: Than you can drill from parent id and use 'find' children in JQ $(''#SVGImageID').find('#gr2').css('visibility','hidden'); Something like this works?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" OnClientClick="test()" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/PumpStation/circle.svg" />

<script>
     function test() { $('#svgimageid').find('#gr1').css('visibility','hidden') });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my asp:Image where is?  How could I use the jquery script if the svg was called in an asp:Image?

Comment: When u want to hide onload or any button click?

Comment: Not onload, but at some event (button click, x value>y value, etc).

Comment: The svg is not displayed when i load the page.

Comment: I dont know what u trying to do...Check in console why not working

Comment: How could I do this depending on a value? For example, if (int i>5) hide the svg group element.

Comment: Post some more code than i could help and give thumbs up if above code works

Comment: Above code doesn't work. In console i get the following errors:
1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined.
I think is because asp:Image doesn't have onClick property.

Comment: Yes above code wont work for u... because it is just a sample code...integrate my code in ur logic

Comment: I did this.  And the result is the one mentioned above. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203968/discussion-between-praveen-gopal-and-ionut).

Comment: Ok. I wrote to you there.